# Concat different values with delimiter

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a few fields in my table, and I want to combine some of them into a string, using `-` as a separator:

```
select 
    concat(
        case when a <> 'a' then concat('A = ', a)
        case when b <> 'b' then concat(' - B = ', b)
        ...
        case when z <> 'z' then concat(' - Z = ', z)
    )
;
```

Now, if A is not included, then my result will start with `-`, and I don't want that. In reality I have like 15 cases so I can't just check if A is 1 again to insert the `-`. What is the easiest solution so that my string never starts with the delimiter?

I know I can just check if it starts with ' - ', but that looks as a dirty solution to me...

Comment: Can you show us a sample table along with the output you want?

Comment: Let's suppose I have a table with 26 fields (A --> Z). All are simple VARCHAR(10)
Possible output: 
C = r - F = z - Y = q - Z = n
I realize my example is badly chosen, but it shouldn't matter...

Comment: Yes, but what is the data and what output do you want?  We can't read your mind.

Comment: I edited my example to be more clear.

Comment: why not get the string as you already can and then just take the sub string from 2 to length -1 if the character index of '-' is 1.  If you use a sub select or cte it will be easy to refer to a column alias name rather than copying/pasting your long case statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand well your issue, you should try something with `concat_ws` like the following code (normally `concat_ws` will skip null values from your CASE statements):

```
SELECT
    CONCAT_WS(
        ' - ', 
        (CASE a WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT('A = ', a) ELSE null END), 
        (CASE b WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT('B = ', b) ELSE null END),
        ...
    )
```

Example below

```
create table table5
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    a int not null,
    b int not null
);
insert table5(a,b) values (0,0),(1,0),(1,1),(0,1),(1,1);

SELECT 
    id, 
    CONCAT_WS( 
        ' - ',  
        (CASE a WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT('A = ', a) ELSE null END),  
        (CASE b WHEN 1 THEN CONCAT('B = ', b) ELSE null END) 
    ) as xxx 
    from table5; 
+----+---------------+
| id | xxx           |
+----+---------------+
|  1 |               |
|  2 | A = 1         |
|  3 | A = 1 - B = 1 |
|  4 | B = 1         |
|  5 | A = 1 - B = 1 |
+----+---------------+
```

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Nice answer Mickaël

Comment: Thx for the example :)